# Existe um seletor css que eu consiga selecionar um input do tipo submit apenas quando ele for acionado/clicado

Tags: css

minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Existe alguma forma de selecionar apenas com css uma tag `<input type="submit">`apenas quando ele for clicada/acionada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu acho que entendi a pergunta de outra forma, acredito que ele queira "disparar" alguma propriedade no clique. E nesse casso seria com o `:active`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Segue código referente a imagem acima:**

```css
[type="submit"]:active {
    box-shadow: none;
    transition: box-shadow 100ms;
}
[type="submit"]:active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px red;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Clique aqui">
```

---

**OBS**

Qualquer elemento pode receber um `:active`

> The `:active` pseudo-class is also typically matched when using the keyboard tab key. It is frequently used on `<a>` and `<button>` HTML elements, **but may not be limited to just those.**

PORTUGUÊS *"A pseudo-classe `:active` também é normalmente usada quando se usa a tecla tab do teclado. É freqüentemente usado em elementos HTML `<a>` e `<button>`, **mas pode não estar limitado apenas a eles.**"*

*Fonte:* https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:active

Comment: Realmente creio que o :active seja o intento da pergunta. :D

Comment: @Sam rapaz deixa a sua resposta tbm uai, ate por uma questão de seo, Pq as vezes as pessoas pesquisam no google mas não sabem ao ser do os termos, e o focus pode ser melhor pra elas. 

Answer (score 5):

Quando você clica no input, ele recebe o estado de `:focus`:

```
input[type=submit]:focus {
  color: red;
}
```

> **Edição:** conforme informado na resposta do Hugo, o `:active` ocorre quando botão é clicado. O `:focus` pode ocorrer 
>   quando o botão for clicado, via tecla TAB ou via script.

Quando o foco é retirado ele volta ao estado original.

**Exemplo:**

```css
input[type=submit]:focus {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit">
```

Comment: Isso ai, não deixa de ser uma opção dependendo do caso

Comment: Valeu! Realmente. :D